# js - call the same value in body onload to an onclick function

Tags: javascript, function

i am trying to get the same value string that i get from the prompt box, to a function that run in onclick event.
is it possible in that kind of way?
Thanks in advance..

```
    <!DOCOTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onLoad = "h1();">

    <form>
    <input type="button" value="function h3()" onClick="h3()">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function h1(){
        var x = prompt("");
        console.log(x);
        return h2(x);
        }

        function h2(str){
        console.log("get value from h1 function" + "   " + str);
        }


        function h3(){
        console.log("return the value from h1 to h2");
        return h2(str);

        }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the variable:

```
var answer;//store it in global scope
function ask(){
  answer=prompt("a question");
}

function h3(){
 alert(answer || "no answer yet...");
}

window.onload=ask;
```

Variables inside of functions are garbage collected when the function returns. So you need to move the variable out of *function scope* into *global scope*. Then its persistent.